# How to insert data in particular column?

Tags: php

The problem is I only know the names of the columns but do not know how many columns in total. There will be other columns.

Comment: too little information perhaps showing us what you have tried so far might help getting some answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about SQL, not PHP. You can use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table SET columnName = 'foo'
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO table(columnName) VALUES('foo')
```

If you need to insert multiple values at the same time, you can use these:

```
INSERT INTO table SET columnName = 'foo', otherColumn = 'bar'
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO table(columnName, otherColumn) VALUES('foo', 'bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or for speed and security:

```
$DATA = array("column"=>"data", "second"=>"...");

$keys = implode("`, `", array_keys($DATA));
$qm = str_repeat("?, ", count($DATA)-1);
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`$keys`) VALUES ($qm ?)")
    ->execute(array_values($DATA));
```